# How to set to NSManagedObject relationship to another NSManagedObject or stack of them in code in CoreData?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

So, I have core data entities:ACCourse , ACStudent.ACCourse has relationship from one to many ACStudents(ACCourse <--->> ACStudent).
I have to set to specific NSManagedObject(that is ACCourse) the relationship in code to other specific NSManagedObject(that is ACStudent).I didn't found any method to do such thing , as for example setting specific NSManagedObject attribute by KVC's setValue.What I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode creates conveniences methods for to-many relations in the `NSManagedObject` subclass. To add a student to a course:

```
[instanceOfACCourse addToNameOfRelationship: acStudentInstance];
```